# Azure Table querying

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm new to Azure Tables and NOSQL in general.

I currently have a table in Azure Tables with about 60,000 rows. It contains job vacancies with columns such as ID (RowKey), Employer (PartitionKey), title, region, category and other columns.

When someone on the website performs a search, the request is sent to an external matching system. The matching system will then return applicable jobs. The matching engine returns for each job the ID and the employer.

A search could contain 10 distinct employers covering 300 jobs. If I was using a SQL Server database I would simply create an "IN" clause on the ID which would be the primary key in order to select those jobs from my table.

With Azure Table's, the recommended approach is to use PartitionKey's (which I have created the Employer on) so my plan was to issue a query for each employer to the table and then union the results, and then finally sort before passing to the UI.

My problem here is that I can't run a query such as "WHERE Employer = "MyEmployer" AND ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6).

What would be the best way to achieve this? I don't want all jobs from an Employer returning as I might not use them all. I want certain jobs from a certain employer based on the ID's I get back.

This is something that I thought should be simple, but so far proving tricky!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem here is that I can't run a query such as "WHERE Employer =
>   "MyEmployer" AND ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6).

You certainly can do `IN` queries though the syntax will be a bit different. This is what you will use assuming you're using REST API and writing query using ODATA syntax:

```
(PartitionKey eq 'MyEmployer' and (RowKey eq '1' or RowKey eq '2' or RowKey eq '3' or RowKey eq '4' or RowKey eq '5' or RowKey eq '6')
```

A few things you would need to consider:

- This will result in full Partition scan. This may not be an issue if the number of entities in a partition are less but could become an issue as the number of entities grow.
- Since the query is passed as query string in the request to table service, there's a limit of number of `or` clauses you can have in your query. If I am not mistaken, max length of a query string is 1024 characters.
- You may want to consider firing many single queries in parallel where each query will be targeting individual entity e.g. `PartitionKey eq 'MyEmployer' and RowKey eq '1'`.

Lastly, you may want to read this blog post from Storage Team: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables.aspx. This will provide you with very good insights.

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful. Would you know a way of achieving this using Linq? I've tried using contains with an array of values, plus  Any but they are both unsupported.

Comment: Haven't tried this code but can you see if this works: `(x=>x.PartitionKey == "MyEmployer" &&
 (x.RowKey == "1" || x.RowKey == "2" ||
  x.RowKey == "3" || x.RowKey == "4" ||
  x.RowKey == "5" || x.RowKey == "6"));`